# How to use pointer/array to implement these methods in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "histo.h"

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
  int histo[256];

  if (args == 2)
  {
    init_histogram(histo);
    cons_histogram(argv[1], histo);
    display_histogram(histo);
  }
  else
    exit(1);

  return 0;
}

histo.h 
#define MAX_CHAR 255 // largest ASCII(Extended) value for characters

typedef unsigned char byte; // may be useful for casting(s)

void init_histogram(int histo[]); // set all elements of the histogram to zero
void cons_histogram(const char string[], int histo[]); // construct the histogram from string
void most_frequent(const int histo[], char* ret_val); // report a most occurring character
void display_histogram(const int histo[]); // display the histogram sparsely
```

I'm given this main.c and histo.h to implement histo.c file following those methods in the header file. I'm confused about the int array histo. display_histogram takes only one parameter and is supposed to print this output:

```
% ./main hgfjkddjkrui3
3 appeared 1 times
d appeared 2 times
f appeared 1 times
g appeared 1 times
h appeared 1 times
i appeared 1 times
j appeared 2 times
k appeared 2 times
r appeared 1 times
u appeared 1 times
```

d was a most often occurrence
Could anyone explain to me what values are supposed to be stored in histo[] in order to get this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably `hist[]` is an array where each element contains the frequency of a given ASCII character, and it is indexed by ASCII character. `init_histogram` is setting it ot 0, and `display_histogram` is printing the non-zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those functions calculate the histogram of a string.

I think the `histo[]` array needs to store the count of each character. Because you have defined `MAX_CHAR` as `255`, I think the `histo[]` array is an array of 256 ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
//vertical HISTOGRAM


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int c,i,j,arr[10],height=0;
system("clear");

for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    arr[i]=0;

 while( ( c=getchar() ) != EOF)
  {
     if(c >= '0' || c <='9')
     ++arr[c-'0'];
     if( arr[c-'0'] > height )
      {
      height = arr[c-'0'];
      } 
  }
printf("\n");
for(j=height ; j>0 ; j--)     // row
 {
  printf("%2d|",j);
  for ( i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++)  // column

    {
    if( j == arr[i] )
     {
     printf(" *|");
     arr[i]--;
     }
     else
         printf("  |");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
  printf("  |");
 for ( i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++)
     printf(" %d|",i);
     printf("\n  ------------DIGITS-------------");
     printf("\n");
return(0);
}
```

[image]